# Laptop boots to white grey lines; BIOS doesn't display properly but can boot

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, graphics

**Hardware specs:**

- ACER 5742G (Core i3 380m, optimus with Nvidia GT540M)
- Replaced primary HDD with Samsung 256GB 830 SSD
- Replaced CD drive with primary HDD (WD Scorpion Blue, 640GB)
- Lspci output available here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qgADBKRW)

**Software:**

- Dual booting Windows 8 Pro and Archlinux x64 on the SSD, with GRUB (non-legacy)

**Problem:**

As of today, when I boot the laptop instead of getting the generic BIOS screen, I get bright white and grey lines on the screen. My SSD is password protected, and if I pound on the keys enough the prompt to enter my password on the drive shows up, I can enter my password (but the screen doesn't update as I enter characters like it normally does). When I get to the OS, the screen flickers briefly and then eventually stops and then behaves normally with no issues.

In a similar vein of weird, during this process there is significant backlight bleed: when the white and grey lines go away and the password prompt shows up, there is a ton of backlight bleed in the bottom left hand corner, that then spreads to the rest of the screen slowly.

I have also noticed that the BIOS has been booting much more slowly lately than usually, may or may not be related.

**What I have tried:**

- Battery pull
- Reboot

**Additional thoughts**

Probably a hardware issue, since it happens right when I start up the computer (no software loaded yet). Appears to post properly, so may be graphics related.

Any ideas on where to go from here? I'm a little confused since once fully booted in the OS it behaves completely fine...

Comment: You may want to run a mem test just to eliminate or confirm that as a suspect even though everything seems to be running well now.

Answer (score 0):

Reset my BIOS settings, issue appears to have disappeared (hit "F2" on the white and grey screen).

Not sure if issue will crop up again, I have no idea what caused it.